# How can a program know if embedded html 'Yes' or 'No' button was pressed in an email?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an application that would need to send an email notification to moderators about a settings change. This email would need to contain two HTML buttons:

- 'yes' : change approved
- 'no' : change not approved

Once my application sends this email with a yes/no button, I would need to track and determine whether 'yes' or 'no' was pressed in the email. My program would need to read and know the response to do the following:

- 'yes' : Allow the settings change request and implement the changes in the program
- 'no' : Discard the settings change request and do not implement the changes in the program

I'm not certain how I can do this, and was wondering if anyone here knows of an existing solution or method that would allow me to achieve this? I was thinking of `webhooks` and something along those lines. Or creating a custom server where the button would make a `post request` on a unique URL and then my program would do a `get request`. Any suggestions or thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: sidenote: if you do this, you'll also have to think about how to ensure nobody unauthorized can just make a request to your endpoint to send a fake "yes" or "no". Maybe it's easier to have the recipient login to the usual interface, if one already exists, and do the yes/no decision there

Comment: That is an excellent point. Thank you. I agree that an authentication method of some kind would be beneficial, or at least a way of ensuring that an unauthorized request is highly unlikely.

Comment: Perhaps I could add an HTML password field that would be apart of the post request when yes or no is pressed.

Comment: frankly, you rather have no choice - you need web server to get requests from buttons or links. It can be POST or even GET request with parameters in URL. Popular method is to send unique number in url to every user and later you can use it to recognize what clicked button. Mails can be display on different programs and they may display one some HTML objects and use one some CSS and they may not run JavaScript (for security reason) so using any JavaScript can be useless.

Comment: BTW: unique number can be used  also to check if it is not fake request, you can also control if someone doesn't click two times.

Comment: BTW: web server means any program which runs all time on public IP and can get HTTP request. It may even run on local computer and use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to access from network - but external server can be more useful because it may works all time when you turn off your local computer. It doesn't have to use frameworks like Flask, Django but using framework you could not only get requests but also display it in browser so you would no need external applications to get information. And you could add options to resend mails, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furas excellently answered your question in the comments, but I would like to show it in practice here.

I had a similar situation a while ago where I needed to be able to have users confirm their email address. The [uuid standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) was of great use to me.

You will need to run this code in a place that has persistent file storage, as I'm using a json file to keep track of the UUIDs for generated links. You should move this to a permanent database/storage solution.

---

**begin edit:**

Note, with this system you don't need to implement a login, as the uuid *should* ensure each link is unique.

**end edit**

---

**server.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import uuid


app = Flask(__name__)
json_filename = "uidfile.json"
expiry_max = 7  # days


def save_json(data):
    with open(json_filename, "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)


def load_json():
    try:
        with open(json_filename) as infile:
            return json.load(infile)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        # return empty dict when file not found
        print(e)
        return {}
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        # return empty dict when file empty
        print(e)
        return {}
    # safety return. should never be reached
    return {}


@app.route("/confirm")
def confirm():
    choice = request.args.get("choice")
    uid = request.args.get("uid")
    if choice and uid:
        uids = load_json()
        if uid in uids:
            # remove the uid from the uids file
            # as it should be single use only
            del uids[uid]
            save_json(uids)
            if choice == "yes":
                # do the "yes" stuff here
                return "You chose wisely..."
            elif choice == "no":
                # do the "no" stuff here
                return "You chose poorly..."
            else:
                # added this just to catch people trying to misuse the
                # endpoint. You would need to log this I think.
                return "You didn't chose..."
        else:
            return "Link expired."
    else:
        # you need both parameters present
        return "Bad request."


@app.route("/add")
def add():
    # note, this endpoint should be protected with an API key or something
    # get the user from the add request
    user = request.args.get("user")
    # set the expiry date for the uid
    expiry = str(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=expiry_max))
    uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    uids = load_json()
    uids[uid] = {"user": user, "expiry": expiry}
    save_json(uids)
    # return the uid so you can use it in the email
    return uid


@app.route("/check_expiry")
def check_expiry():
    # checks if the uids in the file have expired
    # need to be run daily/hourly
    uids = load_json()
    new_uids = {}
    now = datetime.now()
    for uid, value in uids.items():
        if (datetime.strptime(value["expiry"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") - now).days > 0:
            new_uids[uid] = value
        else:
            print(f"UID: {uid} for {value['user']} expired.")
    save_json(new_uids)
    return "OK"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

**testing code**

```py
import requests

base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
confirm_endpoint = "confirm"
add_endpoint = "add"

uid1 = requests.get(f"{base_url}{add_endpoint}?user=somename").text
print(uid1)

uid2 = requests.get(f"{base_url}{add_endpoint}?user=anothername").text
print(uid2)


response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{confirm_endpoint}?uid={uid1}&choice=yes")
print(response.text)

response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{confirm_endpoint}?uid={uid2}&choice=no")
print(response.text)
```

**sample generated json file**

```json
{
    "be07692b-e407-400f-8d83-da5a705b4dc3": {
        "user": "somename",
        "expiry": "2021-09-27 12:58:32.843333"
    },
    "ab7f62c4-03d8-49ea-80f5-4b51e8619211": {
        "user": "somename2",
        "expiry": "2021-09-27 12:58:34.586817"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!